# How to make a function so that it can search any string in a file?

Tags: python, file, search

I am creating a software with a machine learning algorithm(in python) and I am currently setting up an environment that is taking data from a file.

The problem is that I can't find a way for the function to search for any string in the file, so that it can progress to search for specific strings.

I have created some lists that are empty every time the program starts up and are automatically filled(ex. `data.append(data_from_file)`) with the data from my file `environment_data.txt`.

I haven't tried much, because I genuinely don't know what to make it search for any string.

These are the lists.

```
tasks = []
deadlines_month = []
deadlines_week = []
deadlines_days = []
difficulty = []
```

The file format is: It is a little bit faulty but it is a minor problem.

```
Task( ex. Maths)
Month( ex. 4)
Week(From how many weeks the month has ex. 3)
Days(Days of the week, ex. 4)
Difficulty(from 1 to 10, ex. 9)
```

This is the class that appends the lists:

```
class ArrayFix:
def __init__(self, num):
         file = open("environment_data.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    tasks.append(lines[num + 1])
    deadlines_month.append(lines[num + 2])
    deadlines_week.append(lines[num + 3])
    deadlines_days.append(lines[num + 4])
    difficulty.append(lines[num + 5])
    file.close()
```

This is the function to search for string to append the lists.

```
for line in array_fix_num:
file = open("environment_data.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
if str in file.read():
    if str in lines[line]:
        ArrayFix(line)
    else:
        pass
else:
    file.close()
    break
```

What can I put to search for any string in the place of `str` is on the function?

The expected results is for the lists to not be empty but have data from the file but instead they are still empty, because I don't know how to search for any string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can open, read and then close a file and assign the lines to a variable:

```
file = open("environment_data.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

then you can apply some simple checking logic to fine the data you're looking for:

```
data_test_case = "cat"

for line in lines:
    if data_test_case in line:
        DoSomething(line)
```

you could implement a more complex model using Regex:

```
import re
line = "Jan  3 07:57:39 Kali sshd[1397]: Failed password for root from 172.16.12.55 port 34380 ssh2"
new_line = re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+\s+[\d\:]+', line)[0]
```

output :

```
'Jan  3 07:57:39'
```

is this the sort of thing you're thinking of?

Comment: Yeah. I am looking into the regex model you mentioned... Is it possible to make it to check for just string?

Comment: awesome, so what you could do is have multiple regex cases that search for the structures you're looking for, then pass them in to the arrays you specified. 
if you're happy with this answer feel free to accept it! if you need more info let me know !

Comment: Alright! Thank you I think I figured out, I need to create a new class with regex to check for strings!